# 2D version of Shift Theorem

Tags: image-processing, fft, fourier-transform, dft

What is the 2D version of Shift Theorem?

Comment: Don't you mean $DFT\{x_{k+a}\}$ ? Otherwise the equality doesn't hold.

Comment: @Peter K. Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2D version is just the same as the 1D version:
$$
x(n,m) \leftrightarrow X(k,l) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} x(n,m) e^{-j2\pi nk/N - j2\pi ml/M}\\
x(n-a,m-b) \leftrightarrow 
\begin{array}{ccl}
&&\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} x(n-a,m-b) e^{-j2\pi nk/N - j2\pi ml/M} \\
&=& \sum_{n'=0}^{N-1} \sum_{m'=0}^{M-1} x(n',m') e^{-j2\pi (n'+a)k/N - j2\pi (m'+b)l/M}\\
 &=& X(k,l) e^{-j (2\pi ka/N + 2\pi lb/M)}
\end{array}
$$